# approve spender to swap

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, uniswap, cpp-ethereum, sushiswap

i'm trying to swap using 1inch aggregator api and when i try to swap, it says

```
"Not enough allowance. Amount: 4600000000000000. Allowance: 0. Spender: 0x1111111254eeb25477b68fb85ed929f73a960582",
```

my question is.. there is an ERC20 method `approval(address spender, uint256 value)` and my question is...is this method must be send by `eth_call` or `eth_sendRawTransaction`? if i must send it by `eth_sendRawTransaction` do i pay gas to approve balance spend?

Please help

Comment: You have to pay gas to approve balance

Comment: ok thanks very much... so the tnx must be signed and send by raw transaction. Right?